# java error advertence - ignore

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I have a Java problem on my web site (my version is java 7 update 67).
But I can't automate any tests with selenium with this popup. Is there some way to ignore this message? Or don't analyze this certificate?

I am trying to import the certificate in the JVM, but not working! I have tryed to ignore code mixin in security java configuration, but it doesn't work, and I have not found a solution for this problem

See the image on [LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zg87q.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

This to switch selenium to the alert:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
```

Then to see what you can do with the alert, see [Selenium doc for Alerts](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Alert.html)

Comment: It doesn't work. This message is at the system and not at the browser. :(

Comment: Oh. Well then. Selenium only works with web browsers.  You could try using the Java awt robot class in your tests to press enter. and then continue with Selenium.

Comment: hmmm...thanks man!! great idea!! I'm stupid!! sorry have not thought about it